# Expresión regular para letras seguidas de números

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo un formulario con un campo "bastidor" que sólo debería permitir introducir números y letras pero debe tener longitud exacta de 15 caracteres.

```
public class Validaciones {
    public static boolean validarFecha(String fecha){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        //setLenient no permite modificar la fecha a una posible válida.
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        try {
            Date d= sdf.parse(fecha);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Validaciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean validarMatricula(String matricula){
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[\\d]{4}[A-Z]{3}$");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(matricula);
        if (mat.matches()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean validarBastidor(String bastidor){
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9]{15}$");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(bastidor);
        if (mat.matches()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Index.java

```
if(Validaciones.validarMatricula("AAA456789ABCDEF"))
            System.out.println("Bastidor valido");
        else
            System.out.println("Bastidor NO valido");
```

Haga o ponga el formato que ponga, me dice "Bastidor no válido" SIEMPRE. Las demás expresiones regulares las cumple bien.

Comment: ¿Estás usando Java o Javascript? En Java no existe la palabra reservada `var` para declarar variables. Deberías poner String en su defecto.

Comment: En Java. Lo que no sé es si usar KeyListener o KeyTyped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para validar que una cadena cumpla con el formato `XXXXNNN` donde:

- **XXXX**: Son cuatro letras (y ningún número)
- **NNN**: Son tres dígitos numéricos

Puedes usar la expresión regular:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{4}[\d]{3}$
```

Si sólo permites mayúsculas en la matrícula, elimina el rango `a-z` del patrón.

**PD:**

```
^[A-Z]{4}[\d]{3}$     // 4 letras mayúsculas y 3 dígitos numéricos
^[a-zA-Z]{4}[\d]{3}$  // 4 letras mayúsculas y minúsculas y 3 dígitos numéricos
^[\w]{4}[\d]{3}$      // 4 caracteres alfanuméricos (letras y números) y 3 dígitos numéricos
^[\w]{15}$            // 15 caracteres alfanuméricos (letras y números)
```

Comment: Lo valido al final cuando vaya a enviar dicho formulario y si no es el formato correcto pues le mando el focus() a ese campo con un mensaje de alerta para que lo modifique, ¿mejor?

Comment: Genial entonces @omaza1990

Comment: y para alfanumérico de 15 caracteres sería: ^[A-Z0-9]{15}$ ?????

Comment: Exacto. Tienes también el Word character (\w), que te coincidiría con números y letras (tanto mayúsculas como minúsculas) `^[\w]{15}$`

Comment: He agregado algunos ejemplos. Cierra si te ha servido de utilidad. Un saludo!

Comment: No es necesario incluir `\d` o `\w` en una clase de caracteres si el cuantificador aplica a 1 sólo. `^[a-zA-Z]{4}\d{3}$` es exactamente lo mismo y más sencillo de leer.

Comment: Me da fallo la expresión regular de alfanumérica de 15 caracteres.

Comment: Con que patrón y que datos?